# How to update value inside object in firebase cloud firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have data structure like in this image. I need to update boolean value from true to false.

This is my function to perform the update, but it's not working...

The worldIndex and levelIndex a numbers.

```
export const setLevelPassed = (worldIndex, levelIndex) => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    await firestore()
      .collection(auth().currentUser.uid)
      .doc('gameDetails')
      .update(gameData[worldIndex].questions[levelIndex].isLocked = false);
    resolve();
  } catch (e) {
    reject(e);
    console.log('setLevelPassed', e);
  }
});
```

[image]

I tried this way too , but it's not working:

```
export const setLevelPassed = (worldIndex, levelIndex) => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    await firestore()
      .collection(auth().currentUser.uid)
      .doc('gameDetails')
      .update(`gameData[${worldIndex}].questions[${levelIndex}].isLocked`, false);
    resolve();
  } catch (e) {
    reject(e);
    console.log('setLevelPassed', e);
  }
});
```

Comment: Some one please?=]

Answer (score 1):

To update a field in firebase cloud firestore you must write

.update({ field : value, field : value, ... })

```
export const setLevelPassed = (worldIndex, levelIndex) => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    await firestore()
      .collection(auth().currentUser.uid)
      .doc('gameDetails')
      .update({gameData[worldIndex].questions[levelIndex].isLocked: false});
    resolve();
  } catch (e) {
    reject(e);
    console.log('setLevelPassed', e);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Marci , When I try to do like your suggestion , I got error: [Error: TransformError SyntaxError: C:\Users\ionia\Desktop\quizAppNew\src\requests\userRequest.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (81:25)

Comment: Hey @Michael have you more than one field that you will update? When yes you must seperat the fields with a comma.

Comment: I need to update only one field, but it very very nested in the object. just see the example in my code.=]

Comment: Can you try add .data to gameData and questions like so: .update({gameData.data[worldIndex].questions.data[levelIndex].isLocked: false}); I'm not sure if this helps to select the right data structure path.

Comment: [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_gameData.default.data[worldIndex]')]

Comment: Hmm can you  try .update({gameData[worldIndex].data().questions[levelIndex].data().isLocked: false}); sorry for the try and error